# Need for a Question which has been already asked here.

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am searching for a question, but I am unable to find it over here. The question is something like this:

Prove that $$\int\limits_{0}^{1} (1-x^{7})^{1/5} - \int\limits_{0}^{1} (1-x^{5})^{1/7} \ dx =0$$

I am not exactly sure if this is the question, but certainly there is a question of this type.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139393/how-to-show-that-int-01-left-sqrt31-x7-sqrt71-x3-right-dx) is another version with another excellent answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here she is.

[Why is $\int\limits_0^1 (1-x^7)^{1/5} - (1-x^5)^{1/7} dx=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316/why-is-int-01-1-x71-5-1-x51-7-dx-0)

[Use google instead of the built-in search engine.](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%281-x%5E5%29%5E%281/7%29%20%281-x%5E7%29%5E%281/5%29&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: Thank you marvis.